# tensorflowのsess.runを使ってfitting/predictionを行う方法について

Tags: python, tensorflow

tensorflow (2.6.0)を使い始めた者です。
現在プログラムの学習が出来ても、テストが出来ず困っています。

以前にKerasの使用経験はありますが、tensorflowのgraphとsessionの使い方で理解が追いついておりません。みなさまのお知恵を拝借したいです。

学習には以下URLのコードを使用しております。

https://github.com/halhorn/deep_dialog_tutorial

このコード（や他のtensorflowコード）で、配列X,Yをインプットデータとして Sess.run() で使って学習できることは確認しました。学習したweightも保存・読み込みも確認しました。

不明な点を自分なりに勉強した結果、KerasでのModel.fitに相当するものが、Tensorflowでは再度 Sess.run() を使用することがわかりました。
行いたいことは、sess.run() で配列Xだけを使ってYの予測配列を取り出すことです。

具体的にはKerasで以下の様なことをTensorflowでも行いたいです。

```
model.fit(X,Y)
Y_hat = model.predict(X)
```

上記のコードは分かり易いように表示したまでですので、これ以外のコードでも構いません。
もし Sess.run() を使って予測をする手順がわかりましたら、教えていただけると幸いです。

よろしくお願いします。